# Dotnet watch no compila cambios

Tags: vscode, dotnetcore

Tengo una situación con dotnet watch compilando Asp.net Core.
Si hago cambios en el codigo de javascript de una vista .cshtml me muestra:

```
Unable to apply hot reload because of a rude edit.
```

y recompila todo bien,
pero si hago cambios en el codigo de c# .cshtml.cs despues de guardar me sale:

```
No hot reload changes to apply
```

aunque haga cambios significativos.
Hasta hoy funcionaba todo bien y no cambié nada.
Uso VSCode en windows 10.
Gracias.